# Displaying two arrays on same page by merging them into one array - react native

Tags: arrays, react-native

I'm importing two arrays from other files and trying to merge those arrays (sender, traveler) into one array using the spread operator and displaying it using map method. Whenever I'm trying to display one of the data from both of the arrays which are merged, their values are displayed far from each other, even though they are written right next to each other in code.

This is my Sender's class. I have the same as that of Traveler

```js
class Sender {
  constructor(
    snd_f_name,
    snd_l_name,
    snd_id,
    snd_cnic,
    orderTitle,
    pack_weight,
    pack_type,
    snd_dest,
    snd_arr_date
  ) {
    this.snd_f_name = snd_f_name;
    this.snd_l_name = snd_l_name;
    this.snd_id = snd_id;
    this.snd_cnic = snd_cnic;
    this.orderTitle = orderTitle;
    this.pack_weight = pack_weight;
    this.pack_type = pack_type;
    this.snd_dest = snd_dest;
    this.snd_arr_date = snd_arr_date;
  }
}

export default Sender;
```

I'm importing this class and Traveler's class into a single page and then defining its data. This is my code. I'm merging SENDER and TRAVELER into one array i.e. abc2, and displaying value of each of those merged array using map method

```js
    import SENDER from "../data/sender";
    import TRAVELER from "../data/traveler";
    import Sender from "../model/sender";
    import Traveler from "../model/traveler";

    const test = prop => {
      const SENDER = [
        new Sender(
          "Shahnihal",
          "Alwani",
          "u1",
          "123456789",
          "Mobile Phone",
          "500 g",
          "Electronic",
          "New York",
          "20-04-2020"
        )
      ];

      const TRAVELER = [
        new Traveler("Shahzain", "Alwani", "u1", "1234567777", "1 Kg", "Rs. 1000")
      ];

      const abc2 = [...SENDER, ...TRAVELER];
      return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
          {abc2.map((item, key) => (
            <View>
              <Text key={item.snd_id}> {item.snd_f_name} </Text>
              <Text key={item.tr_id}> {item.tr_f_name} </Text>
            </View>
          ))}
        </View>
      );
    };
```

3. [This is my output. I don't know why there is a gap between the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RNzK.jpg)

I'm doing this because I want to display data of both array on same page using flatList but the output was same so I tried to do it with a simpler way for the purpose of testing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `const abc2 = [...SENDER, ...TRAVELER];` add this line which converts array to object.

```
object = Object.assign({}, ...abc2 );
```

Now you can directly use this object in return

```
return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
        <Text>{object.tr_f_name}</Text>
        <Text>{object.snd_f_name}</Text>
        </View>
      );
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, there is no gap now, but with your code, I can get only one value from each array at a time. How can I get multiple values from each array at same time? Plus, even I try to display "Shahzain" above "Shahnihal" by writing its code above, I couldn't do it.. This is another problem

Comment: Yes it will not display "Shahzain" above "Shahnihal" as shahnihal will be rendered first you can create a object and store the array in it.

Comment: I had edited my code check my code once, now you can use object variable to get all you values.

Comment: I tried your updated code but now when I add new data in SENDER or TRAVELER, the old one gets replaced.

Comment: That's okay if you add new data in sender and traveler, the newly added objects will be with the old objects

Comment: Thank you! My code still needs some improvements but your way helped, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's all about styling of your Elements.
You can get this inline-text-effect by wrapping text elements in other text elements:

```js
<View>
  <Text><Text>This writing should fill most of the container </Text><Text>This writing should fill most of the container</Text></Text>       
</View>
```

or you can use Styling with flexbox:

```js
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
  <Text>one</Text><Text>two</Text><Text>Three</Text><Text>Four</Text><Text>Five</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: I did what you said but there is another problem. 
      
         ` <Text> {item.snd_f_name} </Text><Text> {item.tr_f_name} </Text><Text> {item.snd_f_name} </Text>`

output should be:
Shahnihal
Shahzain
Shahnihal

What I'm getting:
Shahnihal

Shahnihal

Shahzain

All the values from SENDER array are outputting together, same for the TRAVELER array. They are not responding to what I have written in code

Comment: I'm new here so I don't really know how to add code in comments or properly format the comments! I hope the above one is understandable

Comment: code in comment = put backtick ` three-times in a row, start your code in next row... and end the codeblock with three backtick's in an new row after your code.
To activate Syntax-highlighting, you can write \`\`\`javascript in your backticks in front of your codeblock....

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with this code below:

```
{abc2.map((item, key) => (
        <View>
          <Text key={item.snd_id}> {item.snd_f_name} </Text>
          <Text key={item.tr_id}> {item.tr_f_name} </Text>
        </View>
      ))}
```

In you array for sender object, you don't have **tr_f_name** key if you see in your Sender class. So, it's rendering empty text component consuming heigh.

Same goes for Traveler class, you don't have **snd_f_name** key.